# Given $x_0>0$ and $a>0$, if $x_{n+1}=\frac{2a^2x_n}{x_n^2 + a^2}$ for every $n\ge0$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=a$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $x_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{2a^2x_n}{x_n^2 + a^2} , a>0.$$

Show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=a.$$

I thought of first proving sequence bounded and then either increasing or decreasing, so that i could establish its convergence. But i couldnot do it. Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you sure about the statement you're trying to prove? The limit of sequence indexed by $n$ can't be something that depends on $n$...

Comment: Should be $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = a$, right?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you have $x_n >0$, $\forall n$, then $x_n^2 + a^2 \geq 2ax_n$.

It implies that that $x_{n+1} \leq \frac{2a^2x_n}{2ax_n} = a$.

It means that $x_n \leq a$, for all $n \geq 1$ (maybe not $n=0$, i.e $x_0 > a$).

So, you also have $x_{n+1} \geq \frac{2a^2x_n}{2a^2} = x_n$, (because $ 0 < x_n \leq a$).

You can conclude that this sequence is converge.

Comment: problem is that $x_0$ is not given

Comment: You are right. We only know that this sequence is positive.

Comment: Can you elaorate what you have written

Comment: How did denominator became $2ax_n$

Comment: It is simple: because $x_n, a >0$, then $x_n^2 + a^2 \geq 2ax_n$.

Comment: Why is this so?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you proved sequence is increasing?

Answer (score 3):

$x_1=a\tanh(\theta)\Rightarrow x_2=a\frac{2\tanh(\theta)}{1+\tanh^{2}(\theta)}=a\tanh(2\theta)\Rightarrow ...\Rightarrow x_n=a\tanh(2^{n-1}\theta)$

Comment: i have never seen this kind of stuff in sequences(substitution). Your answer looks good. Please elaborate more

Comment: Shouldnot the last term be $atanh(2^n\theta)$ ?

Comment: Hyperbolic function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function

Comment: I know about hyberbolic functions. But how do i prove this is convergent sequence

Comment: $x_0>0\Rightarrow 0<x_1=a\frac{2ax_0}{a^2+x_0^2} \leq a$ If $x_0=a$,it's really easy situation. so we suppose $x_0\neq a\Rightarrow x_1<a$, so the substitution works $0<x_1=a\tanh (\theta) <a$

Comment: And $\tanh (2^{n-1}\theta)$, where $\theta$ is a positive angle. Just by definition, $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \tanh (x)=1$